# Uncheck and Check checkbox in a switch case

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, leaflet

When a checkbox will be checked or unchecked, I want the icon to appear or dissappear. Below I am showing how the icon url path looks. Is there any way I can do that? I've been trying myself to add this code to the switch case, but I'm a beginner with js & jquery and I don't know what Im doing wrong.

```
$('#someId').change(function()  {

        if(this.checked)    {
            $(icon = greenIcon).show(1);
        }
        else    {
            $(icon = greenIcon).hide(1);
        }

    });

    $('#someId2').click(function()  {

        if(this.checked)    {
            $(icon = yellowIcon).show(1);
        }
        else    {
            $(icon = yellowIcon).hide(1);
        }

    });

    $('#someId3').click(function()  {

        if(this.checked)    {
            $(icon = redIcon).show(1);
        }
        else    {
            $(icon = redIcon).hide(1);
        }

    });

    $('#someId4').click(function()  {

        if(this.checked)    {
            $(icon = blueIcon).show(1);
        }
        else    {
            $(icon = blueIcon).hide(1);
        }

    });
```

into this

```
switch (feature.properties.status) {
        case 0:   
            icon = greenIcon; break;
        case 1:
        case 11:
        case 12:
            icon = yellowIcon; break;
        case 2: 
        case 21:    
        case 22:    
            icon = redIcon; break;
        case 5: 
        default:
            icon = blueIcon; break;
}
```

Icons are added to the code like this:

```
var greenIcon = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: L.Icon.Default.imagePath + 'marker-icon-ok.png'});
var redIcon = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: L.Icon.Default.imagePath + 'marker-icon-err.png'});
var yellowIcon = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: L.Icon.Default.imagePath + 'marker-icon-warn.png'});
var blueIcon = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: L.Icon.Default.imagePath + 'marker-icon-sleep.png'});
```

So when a checkbox is checked or unchecked, the icon would appear or dissappear. Is it possible?

Comment: If I understand correctly (since I'm not familiar with leaflet etc.) you want to check whether the checkbox is checked or not on `change()` of the "ticked" checkbox? And you want to use a switch to determine which icon to show?

Comment: @Jorrex sorry for such a late reply, I'm trying to hide and show the icons on my map by using checkbox. Its pretty hard for me, because the icons are in a js, not in html or css. Im trying to get into them using switch case, but it wont help... I've also got an idea. Im going to try to create a div within the switch case, but all my tries are still failing.. I don't really know what to do as all the answers here not really help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not quite sure if this answers your question, but you could toggle a class when the input changes, and handle what is shown in css/sass.

Simple example:

```
$('.checkboxInput').change(function(){
    $(this).parent().toggleClass('showIcon');
    alert('Is the checkbox checked? This is ' + $(this).prop('checked') );
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Airrudi/ffvmgebe/1/

Answer (score 0):

How about no switch statement? Doing it with data attributes will make it much easier to add things later (in my opinion)

https://jsfiddle.net/stevenkaspar/v43egwdx/1/

```
<input data-icon-target='#i_1' data-has-icon='true' checked type='checkbox'/>
<span class='icon' id='i_1'>icon 1</span>

$('[data-has-icon="true"]').click(function(event){
  var target_id = $(this).data('iconTarget');
  $(target_id).toggleClass('hidden');
})
```